# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' simple problem with my list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

MY CODE:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
doubled_numbers = []

for num in numbers:
    doubled_numbers = num * 2
    doubled_numbers.append(doubled_numbers)

print(doubled_numbers)
```

I GOT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/neman/Desktop/Junior Developer Vezbe/list comprehension.py", line 12, in <module>
    doubled_numbers.append([doubled_numbers])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have no idea why doesn't work, am I missing something or there is a typo? This is a simple thing but it bothers me very much

Comment: ``doubled_numbers = num * 2`` will over-write with ``int`` value, instead do  ``doubled_numbers.append(num * 2)`` & remove line above that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doubled_numbers = num*2` overrides the list `doubled_numbers` into an integer (`num*2`).

To fix this you will have to change the name of the variable to something like `new_number` changing your code to:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
doubled_numbers = []

for num in numbers:
    new_number = num * 2
    doubled_numbers.append(new_number)

print(doubled_numbers)
```

Also, you could remove a line of code and directly append the value of `num*2` to your list:

```
doubled_numbers.append(num*2)
```

and then remove the line of code above it.

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding `doubled_numbers` in `doubled_numbers = num * 2`

change variable name like:

```
for num in numbers:
    doubled_number = num * 2
    doubled_numbers.append(doubled_number)
```